# Dial a phone number with less than symbols in a PhoneGap iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap application, which involves using the native dialer. I'm using this code to dial numbers programmatically:

```
(void) dialPhone:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options {
    NSString* url;
    NSString* number = [options valueForKey:@"number"];
    //NSLog(@"number: %@", number);
    if([number hasPrefix:@"tel://"]) {
        url = number;
    }
    else {
        // escape characters such as spaces that may not be accepted by openURL
        url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", number];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

And it works perfectly with one exception: I can't dial numbers like '10' (full url is tel://10). The application simply does nothing. No alerts, no errors. However, if I add some more symbols before the actual number I need, like '000', it works.
Really looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone encounters the same problem, here is my workaround: I've put '?1'after the number, so full URL became 'tel:10?1' and that did the trick.